# Need help understanding TCP Channels

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration

I have a machine running that sends out status information over TCP to an IP address and port you set on the machine. If I use the command line for the machine on that IP address and run "nc -l " I get the status data from the machine. I am trying to build a Java Spring application to ingest this but all the Java TCP tutorials talk about setting channel names and subscribing to channels? Are channels something that are built on top of TCP and my machine just isn't using channels or is there some default channel listened on when you run the command line "nc -l " command? Please Help I'm very confused

EDIT 1: Adding first attempt code that I can't get to integrate with the Spring application nor can I get the data to store in Spring JPA

```
public class EchoMultiServer {


    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void start(int port) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true)
                new EchoClientHandler(serverSocket.accept()).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            stop();
        }

    }

    public void stop() {
        try {

            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static class EchoClientHandler extends Thread {
        private Socket clientSocket;
        private PrintWriter out;
        private BufferedReader in;

        @Autowired
        PowerStationService powerStationService;
//this service connects to the repository to store the data

        public EchoClientHandler(Socket socket) {
            this.clientSocket = socket;
        }

        public JSONObject mapJsonInput(String incomingText){
            try{
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(incomingText);
                return json;
            } catch (JSONException e){
                System.out.println("JSONException " + e);
                return null;
            }

        }

        public JSONObject run() {
            try {
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder textBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                int c = 0;
                int leftCaratCount=0;
                int rightCaratCount=0;
                while ((c = in.read()) != -1) {
                    char character = (char) c;
                    textBuilder.append(character);
                    if (character == '{') {
                        leftCaratCount++;
                    } else if (character == '}') {
                        rightCaratCount++;
                        if (rightCaratCount == leftCaratCount) {
                            System.out.println(textBuilder);
                            JSONObject registrationJson = mapJsonInput(textBuilder.toString());
                            System.out.println("we got em");
                            powerStationService.save(new PowerStation(registrationJson.get("D").toString(), registrationJson.get("G").toString(), Integer.parseInt(registrationJson.get("Y").toString()), Integer.parseInt(registrationJson.get("S").toString()), registrationJson.get("C").toString(), registrationJson.get("Z").toString(), registrationJson.get("V").toString()));
                            out.println("000250{\"A\":\"45514\",\"C\":\""+registrationJson.get("Y")+"\",\"E\":\"30,5\",\"G\":\""+registrationJson.get("G")+"\",\"H\":\"0\",\"K\":\"1\",\"M\":\"123456\",\"N\":\"" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "\",\"O\":\"13371\",\"P\":\"" + clientSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress() + "\",\"S\":\"60000\",\"U\":\"\",\"V\":\"\",\"W\":\"https://admin.chargenow.top/cdb-socket-api/v1/socketserver/common\",\"X\":\"0\",\"Y\":\"FJC\",\"Z\":\"\"}");
                            in.close();
                            out.close();
                            clientSocket.close();
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EchoMultiServer server = new EchoMultiServer();
        server.start(13370);
    }

}
```

EDIT 2: Additionally I attempted to use the example from the Spring Examples Github to see if it could receive messages on the port I tried. I'm able to use NetCat to see the ServerOut messages but the application isn't receiving responses back

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SampleProperties.class)
public class TcpAsyncBiDirectionalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TcpAsyncBiDirectionalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
@Configuration 
class ServerPeer {

    private final Set<String> clients = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    @Bean
    public AbstractServerConnectionFactory server(SampleProperties properties) {
        return Tcp.netServer(properties.getServerPort()).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow serverIn(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Tcp.inboundAdapter(server))
                .transform(Transformers.objectToString())
                .log(msg -> "received by server: " + msg.getPayload())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow serverOut(AbstractServerConnectionFactory server) {
        return IntegrationFlows.fromSupplier(() -> "seed", e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
                .split(this.clients, "iterator")
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, "payload"))
                .transform(p -> "sent by server Hello from server")
                .handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server))
                .get();
    }

    @EventListener
    public void open(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        if (event.getConnectionFactoryName().equals("server")) {
            this.clients.add(event.getConnectionId());
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void close(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        this.clients.remove(event.getConnectionId());
    }

}

    enter code here
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP is just one of those protocols implemented as channel adapters in Spring Integration.

See more info in the theory: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ChannelAdapter.html

And here is a list of all the supported protocols in Spring Integration:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/endpoint-summary.html#spring-integration-endpoints

What those tutorials are talking about is a messaging channel internal to your application logic. It has nothing to do with external protocol, like yours TCP/IP. You just need to understand for your self if your application is going to be client for that IP host/port or it is going to be a server opening respective socket:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip

Comment: Wow thank you, this is awesome! I was worried no one would respond. So the TCP stream I'm trying to receive seems to be sent without any channel adapter, it's just open to anything on that port. How do I get Spring to intake that? When I try it seems to try to limit it to only what's on a channel.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fully understand what is going on. Never worked with `nc`. Would you mind to share in your question what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thank you for being so responsive, I'll add more info about what I've tried to help explain it

Comment: OK. It looks like `nc -l` indeed becomes a TCP/IP server on the specific port: https://www.varonis.com/blog/netcat-commands/. So, what you need is to use a `TcpReceivingChannelAdapter` from Spring Integration together with the `TcpNetServerConnectionFactory` to become similar server for your clients. Be sure use the proper messages delimiter to let your Spring server to divide one package from another! All of the info is present in the doc for TCP/IP I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: yeah that's what nc -l does but it seems like the channel Adapters make me name a channel and the data I'm receiving isn't sent over a named channel nor does it use new line characters as delimiters. It's all sent as JSON so I have made my code look for the end of the brackets when there is an even number of open and close brackets

Comment: I think you really need to make yourself familiar with EIP: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/ and understand what is endpoint, message and channel. You indeed can accept data from TCP and relay it down to JPA using Spring Integration. You really need to agree with your clients to send some delimiter in the end. Otherwise you won't be able to parse packages properly. It really not worth it to count opening closing brackets...